# Storing more users in a ranking table

Tags: javascript

I want to store more users on my rankings table, and display their first name and last name on the table. But every-time a new user registers, its replaces the first user on the table. How do I fix this? I've created a JSFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/MuddasarAshfaq/qvv0cffh/1/)

```
/* Register */
function storeUserDetail() {
    var fNameInput = document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value;
    var lNameInput = document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value;
    var uNameInput = document.getElementById("userNameInput").value;
    var pWordInput = document.getElementById("passWordInput").value;
    var storeDetails = {};
    storeDetails.FirstName = fNameInput
    storeDetails.LastName = lNameInput
    storeDetails.Username = uNameInput
    storeDetails.Password = pWordInput
    localStorage[storeDetails.Username] = JSON.stringify(storeDetails);                  
}

/* Log In */
function loginUser() {
    var Username = document.getElementById("uNameInput").value;
    var Password = document.getElementById("pWordInput").value;
    var storeDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage[Username]);
    storeDetails.Username = document.getElementById("uNameInput").value;
    storeDetails.Password = document.getElementById("pWordInput").value;
    localStorage.loggedInUser = Username;
}

/* Rankings Table */
function displayTable() {
    var getData = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]); 
    var highScoreTable = "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>\n";
    for(var key in localStorage) {
        if(key !== localStorage.loggedInUser) {
            highScoreTable += "<tr><td>" + getData.FirstName + "</td><td>" + getData.LastName + "</td></tr>";
        }
    } 
    document.getElementById('rankTable').innerHTML = highScoreTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `getData` should be a function. It works for me when dispalyTable is

```
/* Rankings Table */
function displayTable() {
    var getData = function(key) { return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]); }
    var highScoreTable = "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>\n";
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (key !== 'loggedInUser') {
            var data = getData(key);
            highScoreTable += "<tr><td>" + data.FirstName + "</td><td>" + data.LastName + "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('rankTable').innerHTML = highScoreTable;
}
```

I updated `getData` and also checking `key` against local storage key `'loggedInUser'` instead of value. Or it can be `if(localStorage[key] !== localStorage.loggedInUser)`

https://jsfiddle.net/wapapzyd/